# React hook setState causing infinite renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

---

I wonder why this gets stuck in infinite renders as soon as I set it's value coming from backend API.
**I don't want to stop it using useEffect() as I need to use it to re render after the values have been assigned**

CODE :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import FormCheckLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FormCheckLabel';
import './CheckForms.css';
// import Scrollspy from '../Scrollspy/Scrollspy';
import axios from 'axios';

const CheckForms = () => {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
    const fetchList = async () => {
        try {
            const res =  await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/items`);
            const list =  res.data.response;    
            // setMenu(list); // <-- This is causing ulimited renders ! //
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
        };
    };
    fetchList();
    console.log("something"); 
    return (
        <div>    
        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckForms;
```

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot place `fetchList();` outside `useEffect()` because,

when component is mounted, `fetchList()` is called, it sets state and component rerenders.

again `fetchList()` is executed and again sets state and comoenent again rerenders. it forms an infinite loop.

you must do
`useEffect(()=>fetchList(),[])`
or execute it on an event

Answer (score 0):

you need `useEffect` for this. Otherwise `fetchList` will be called on each re render.

So your infinite loop comes from :

`fetchList()` => `setMenu()` => `render()` => `fetchList()` => `setMenu()` and so on ...

> I don't want to stop it using useEffect() as I need to use it to re
> render after the values have been assigned

`useEffect(callback, [triggers])` second parameter is here exactly for that, control when a re render should happen, based on props/state changes